# Flutter web - how to save excel file to the device

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with saving data to the device.
I have base64 String that I need to save to the device as an excel file.
Everything happens on web.
All I found so far are mobile solutions that doesn't work.

Could you please help :)

This is the code that I have currently. It saves the file, however it I can't open it afterwards so there has to be something wrong on the way. Since this solution writes the file I'm guessing I'm converting something wrongly.

```
    //base64StringFile is the file I'm getting from the web. It's a String
    Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(base64StringFile);
    File file = File.fromRawPath(bytes);

    final blob = html.Blob([file]);
    final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    final anchor = html.document.createElement('a') as html.AnchorElement
      ..href = url
      ..style.display = 'none'
      ..download = 'myFileName';
    html.document.body.children.add(anchor);

    anchor.click();

    html.document.body.children.remove(anchor);
    html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.fromRawPath` interprets the given bytes as path information relating to the filesystem - it's not relevant here.

Instead, create your blob with the bytes directly like so, and don't use a `File` object.

Note that the byte list is enclosed in another list.

Additionally, you should specify the [Excel mime type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) when doing so.

```dart
final blob = html.Blob([bytes], 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   //Method 2:
  import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html1;
   //Method 1: 
  import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

     
    exportExcelForWeb(String base64) {
    //Method 1: 
      // launch("data:application/octet-stream;base64,${base64}");
    
    //Method 2:
    
      final anchor = html1.AnchorElement(href: 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,$base64')..target = 'blank';
      // add the name
      anchor.download = 'Export_file.xlsx';
      // trigger download
      html1.document.body.append(anchor);
      anchor.click();
      anchor.remove();
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.